# How do I find the type declaration of an identifier using the Java Tree Compiler API?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, preprocessor, javac, java-compiler-api

I have the name of a variable/identifier, say, `x`, and the `JCCompilationUnit` and [`Scope`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/javac/tree/com/sun/source/tree/Scope.html). Is there a way to find the type of `x`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 public Symbol getSymbol(CompilationUnitTree cut, JCStatement stmt, List<JCExpression> typeParams, Name varName, List<JCExpression> args) {
    java.util.List<Type> typeSyms = getArgTypes(typeParams, cut, stmt);
    java.util.List<Type> argsSyms = getArgTypes(args, cut, stmt);
    final Scope scope = getScope(cut, stmt);
    Symbol t = contains(scope, typeSyms, varName, argsSyms); //first lookup scope for all public identifiers
    TypeElement cl = scope.getEnclosingClass();
    while (t == null && cl != null) { //lookup hierarchy for inacessible identifiers too
        t = contains(elementUtils.getAllMembers(cl), typeSyms, varName, argsSyms);
        final TypeMirror superclass = cl.getSuperclass();
        if (superclass != null) {
            cl = (TypeElement) ((Type) superclass).asElement();
        }
    }
    return t;
}

public Symbol getSymbol(Name varName, Symbol accessor, CompilationUnitTree cut, JCStatement stmt) {
    if (varName.contentEquals("class")) {
        Symbol javaLangClassSym = getSymbol(cut, stmt, null, elementUtils.getName("java.lang.Class"), null);
        JCIdent id = tm.Ident(javaLangClassSym);
        JCExpression mName = tm.Select(id, elementUtils.getName("forName"));
        JCLiteral idLiteral = tm.Literal(accessor.toString());
        JCMethodInvocation mi = tm.Apply(List.<JCExpression>nil(), mName, List.<JCExpression>of(idLiteral));
        Symbol s = getSymbol(mi, cut, stmt);
        return s;
    }
    accessor = getTypeSymbol(accessor);
    java.util.List<Symbol> enclosedElements = getEnclosedElements(accessor, cut, stmt);
    Symbol s = contains(enclosedElements, null, varName, null);
    return s;
}
```

I ended up writing a full [class with resolving methods](http://code.google.com/p/dp4j/source/browse/src/main/java/com/dp4j/ast/Resolver.java). Inheriting it, or passing in the TreeMaker (and other parameters) it can be made static. Should someone find it worthwile, a patch is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Scope`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/javac/tree/com/sun/source/tree/Scope.html) object has a method [`getLocalElements()`,](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/javac/tree/com/sun/source/tree/Scope.html#getLocalElements%28%29) which can be iterated over. Each element can then be asked by its name, and when this is the right one (and it is a variable, too), you can get its type.

This is the concept, untested:

```
private final static Set<ElementKind> variableKinds =
       Collections.unmodifiableSet(EnumSet.of(ElementKind.FIELD, ElementKind.ENUM_CONSTANT,
                                              ElementKind.PARAMETER, ElementKind.LOCAL_VARIABLE));

public Type getTypeOfVariable(Scope scope, String varName)
{
   for(Element e : scope.getLocalElements()) {
       if(variableKinds.contains(e.getKind()) && e.getName().equals(varName)) {
           return e.getType();
       }
   }
   throw new NoSuchElementException("No variable " + varName + " in " + scope);
}
```

**Edit:** Yeah, really untested (there is no `getType()` method).

So, how to get from a `Element` (or VariableElement) from its type?

The `Trees` class has some utility methods allowing the retrieval of a `Tree` or `TreePath` from the `Element`, and thus we can get a `VariableTree` (since this came from a variable declaration). The `VariableTree` now has a `getType()` method, which returns a `Tree` - but in fact this is one of `PrimitiveTypeTree`, `ParametrizedTypeTree`, `ArrayTypeTree` and `IdentifierTree` (for simple reference types as well as type variables). So, if you only want to print the type, this may be enough. Otherwise, again with the `Trees` class we now can get a TypeMirror for this type.

(I did something similar once when I tried to write a new Doclet which would also output the formatted source code. Terrible flipping between all those APIs.)

Comment: Slightly relevant bug I filed trying: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7017477 (consider voting)

Comment: I answered, not to steal your thunder, but because the solution was more complicated.