# How to retrieve javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror of com.sun.source.tree.*TypeTree?

Tags: java, annotation-processing, java-annotations

I wanted to analyse a method body during compilation time and potentially introduce a minor modification to it. I have used **com.sun.source.util.Trees.getTree(ExecutableElement)** and **TreeVisitor**. Unfortunately, **TreeVisitor.visit*Type(...)** methods don't provide a full type path (for instance instead of **java.util.List** visitor returns just **List**).

The only reasonable option that I have found was **Trees.getTypeMirror(TreePath)** and **Trees.getPath(CompilationUnitTree, Tree)**. As expected it doesn't work for types defined outside the current compilation unit (I don't have any idea how to access a compilation unit that contains **java.util.List** definition).

I also thought about imports analysis, but it doesn't solve the problem with wildcard imports.

I have also read responses to issue [How do I find the type declaration of an identifier using the Java Tree Compiler API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881389/how-do-i-find-the-type-declaration-of-an-identifier-using-the-java-tree-compiler)
which seems a bit similar to my problem, however, the code section lacks a lot of methods definitions.